# The conversion of the varchar overflowed an int column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Im trying to format a smalldatetime to dd/mm/yyyy.

So I'm doing this query:

```
Select
right('0' + rtrim(day(mydate)),2) + '/' + right('0' + rtrim(month(mydate)),2) + '/' + rtrim(year(mydate))
from mydates
```

but I´m getting this error:

> The conversion of the varchar overflowed an int column.

Comment: Or you could stop storing date's as strings in the first place?

Comment: It was not a string, it was a smalldatetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would be a lot easier

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), mydate, 103) FROM mydates
```

103 specifies dd/mm/yyyy format but see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CONVERT_TSQL%29;k%28SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1%29;k%28SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1%29;k%28MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT%29;k%28DevLang-TSQL%29&rd=true) page to see the other possibilities